# PHP While Loop Question

Tags: php

How can I turn the code below into a single array when its in the while loop? An example would help.

Here is my PHP code.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
    $category = $row['category'];
    $url = $row['url'];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off mawg's solution and your new requirement:

```
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)) {
  $data[$row['category']] = $row['url'];
}
```

This would create an associative array with the category name as the key.

Or you could do:

```
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)) {
  $data[] = array(
    'row' => $row['url'],
    'category' => $row['category'],
  );
}
```

Which would create an array of associative arrays that would contain the URL and category for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
$urls = array();
$Categories = Array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
    $Categories[] = $row['category'];
    $urls[] = $row['url'];
}
```

Comment: I want to put them all together if possible `array()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$allRows = array(); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc))
{  
    $allRows[] = $row;    
}
```